# New Math Teacher Seeking Advice

Tags: teaching

I am new to teaching math, especially middle school math. My own math education was limited to high school and college calculus. These were painful experiences. How to do I go about learning to teach middle school math?

More importantly, I want to tell my student WHY/WHAT FIELDS/CAREERS require the maths I will be teaching.

Comment: You are asking two questions, which seem quite different to me. It would be better to ask your question about learning how to teach and your question about fields that need the math separately.

Comment: Middle school math? All of STEM requires that. Also anything financial. This is not meant to be a complete list.

Comment: General advice: Get a good textbook, and follow it exactly.  For math careers ... try the internet.  Example: http://weusemath.org/?page_id=800

Comment: I imagine that for most middle schoolers, relating content to careers is of little motivational impact.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you chose to become a math teacher when you disliked math in high school and college? (Not a snark; I'm trying to understand the context of your question.)

Comment: I didn't like the calculus I took in high school or calculus because I had anxiety about it; I then lost confidence.  Prior to that, I enjoyed math.  I'm trying to pinpoint for myself AND for my students how to be comfortable with math.  Sadly, many of the people I know who teach math were always good at math.  I'm coming from a perspective were I was good.....and lost confidence.

Answer (score 13):

The fields & careers it is good for is the least important part, in my opinion.

You don't say what math topics it is. That might help us answer more effectively.

I am guessing that you are uncomfortable with math at any level. If you accepted a position teaching it, you owe it to your students to get past your discomfort. You will want to re-learn what you're going to be teaching, and find the joy in it. (Most of us who answer here really love math. You can too.)

I'd suggest you start by getting an online subscription to [Beast Academy](https://beastacademy.com/), a curriculum originally written for gifted kids, but usable by most students, for arithmetic up through much of what's called pre-algebra. Start at their Level 1. It will be too easy for you. While you're working through it, think about how you'd teach that stuff to 1st or 2nd graders. There may be some challenge problems that challenge you. Great. Have fun playing with them. Savor the experiences you have.

When you get to Level 2, you'll find a few more challenges. That's ok. Play around. Slow down.

But if you're already teaching, you might want to skip around. See which Beast topics match what you'll be teaching in the next few weeks. (You might find them in any of the levels, from 3 to 5, possibly lower.) Print out a page of puzzles. If you can convince your students these puzzles are especially fun (they are!), then you are a good middle school teacher.

Of course there are ed school programs in how to teach math, and if you haven't done any of that, maybe you could pick up a textbook and see if it has any ideas you like.

Tell us more details about your situation, and we can give you more targeted ideas.

Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

I highly recommend that you practice. Practice doing the types of problems you are teaching. There are so many sources for you in this day and age. Khan Academy is a great start. There are also Youtube videos by an endless number of math people. Students can tell when a teacher is confident and are often unkind to a nervous one. The extra prep you do before each class will be well worth it.
You got through calculus while in college. Middle school topics should feel far less intimidating to you.

(I agree with Sue, the "When will I use this" is far less important, although at some point we all get this. Avoid the answer "You won't, but the smart kids might". Especially with lower grades, I stay away from jobs and talk about the math in my life. Not getting ripped off at a store for one. Managing your money. In the kitchen, using recipes, and especially adjusting them up or down. This is a great way to talk about why we need to be comfortable with fractions.)

You still might edit the question to better focus on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

For the applicability of the math, you should just google the topics online and collect the info.

More importantly, it helps to believe that there is math intuition in every human mind. The student doesn't get something because they haven't yet come to tap into that particular intuition. That way, you are never likely to fully give up on a student. You feel like the student's intuition is always around the corner. And that's a perennially motivating space to be in.

Of course, in your experience of teaching you should work towards tapping into your own intuition for the maths you teach. As you feel more convinced, your students benefit more.